# Tomcat JNDI realm logging

Tags: tomcat, logging, ldap

I have added the below realm in server.xml in order to enable ldap authentication in tomcat.

```
  <Realm className="com.speedlegal.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
            connectionName="name" 
            connectionPassword="pswd" 
            connectionURL="ldaps://domain:3269"
            alternateURL="ldaps://domain:3269"  
            userBase="DC=legal,DC=regn,DC=net" 
            userSubtree="true" 
            userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})" 
            roleBase="OU=Groups,DC=xxx,DC=yyy"
            roleSubtree="true"
            roleName="CN"
            commonRole="User" />
```

I want to LOG whats happening inside this. Is there any way to achieve this? Because I wanna know how the ldap server is actually being queried from tomcat.

Comment: What have you tied thus far?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I added org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.realm.useParentHandlers = true
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.useParentHandlers = true 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = -1  in logging.properties file and now it works.

Comment: Sounds like you should answer your own question, here.

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL 
org.apache.catalina.realm.useParentHandlers = true
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.useParentHandlers = true
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = -1
```

in logging.properties file and now it works.